# OpenCV putText UTF-8 characters

Tags: opencv, utf-8, ascii

Does anybody have alternative to `OpenCV` putText (with UTF-8 characters supported) ? As already said, `putText` is only working for ASCII characters, but not for `UTF-8` such as `šŠčČžŽ`?

Comment: Nobody has the answer ?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: You have to do it by loading a font file. You'll need Open CV 3. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv

Answer (score 4):

If OpenCV was built **with Qt support** you can use [`cv::addText()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html?#addtext) to write that string:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\\snowflake.jpg");
if (img.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed imread()" << std::endl;
    return;
}

cv::addText(img, "áéőúöüóí", cv::Point(100, 50), cv::fontQt("Times"));
```

However, if OpenCV was built **without Qt support**, calling `cv::addText()` will crash your application and the following error will be printed to the console:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in cv::fontQt, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 409
```

Comment: I tried to see if this is supported in opencv for python, but it doesn't look like it is yet.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what language are you using. From Python I'd use the PIL's text drawing function:

```
draw.text((0, 0), unicode("áéőúöüóí","utf-8"), font=font, fill=(255,255,255))
```