# Load TrueType Font to OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Can we load a custom TrueType font and use it with `cv2.putText` function ?

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Answer (score 38):

In OpenCV, only a subset of Hershey fonts are supported.

In `opencv2/core.hpp`, you can find this enum HersheyFonts.

```
//! Only a subset of Hershey fonts
enum HersheyFonts {
    FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX        = 0, //!< normal size sans-serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN          = 1, //!< small size sans-serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX         = 2, //!< normal size sans-serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX        = 3, //!< normal size serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX        = 4, //!< normal size serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX)
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL  = 5, //!< smaller version of FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX = 6, //!< hand-writing style font
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX = 7, //!< more complex variant of FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX
    FONT_ITALIC                 = 16 //!< flag for italic font
};
```

You can try PIL.ImageFont if you want to use custom font.

A basic example is presented here:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import cv2
import time

## Make canvas and set the color
img = np.zeros((200,400,3),np.uint8)
b,g,r,a = 0,255,0,0

## Use cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_XXX to write English.
text = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime()) 
cv2.putText(img,  text, (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (b,g,r), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

## Use simsum.ttc to write Chinese.
fontpath = "./simsun.ttc"     
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 32)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((50, 100),  "国庆节/中秋节 快乐!", font = font, fill = (b, g, r, a))
img = np.array(img_pil)

## Display 
cv2.imshow("res", img);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("res.png", img)
```

[image]

Comment: Very good answer, it is working in a python 3.9 environment as well.

Answer (score 24):

For new viewers, OpenCV supports custom fonts since OpenCV 3.0.0 via the FreeType2 class. See here some nice sample code: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html

Comment: Anyone got a python code snippet for this? I can't get it working

Comment: For Python, you would need to install the `opencv-contrib-python` module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50921014/145504) for a code sample.

Comment: Be warned: The pre-built wheels for opencv not always contain these freetype classes. On my Mac they do, but on Linux they don't.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

You can also use the library PILasOPENCV to be found at https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV to use truetype fonts in combination with Python OpenCV. PIL or Pillow are not needed. The module depends on the library freetype-py. Fonts would be imported like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import PILasOPENCV as Image
import PILasOPENCV as ImageDraw
import PILasOPENCV as ImageFont
import cv2
# was: from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 18)
print(font)
im = Image.open("lena.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
text = "Lena's image"
draw.text((249,455), text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
# in PIL:
# print(font.getsize(text))
# mask = font.getmask(text)
print(ImageFont.getsize(text, font))
mask = ImageFont.getmask(text, font)
print(type(mask))
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
im.show()
```

This library is a wrapper around the common used PIL functions but works internally with OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of @Pavlos Fragkiadoulakis: here is an example of using OpenCV 4.8.0 to create an empty binary image with text and custom font in Python.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

text = str(-1.234)
font_height = 400
thickness = 1

# load font and check text size
ft = cv.freetype.createFreeType2()
ft.loadFontData("Seven Segment.ttf", 0)
width, height = ft.getTextSize(text, font_height, thickness)[0]


# create empty white image (slightly bigger than text size)
binary_image = np.ones((int(1.05*height), int(1.05*width)), dtype=np.uint8) * 255

# adjust text positioning
text_origin = (0, height+5)

# add text to image
ft.putText(binary_image, text, text_origin, font_height, (0, 0, 0), thickness, cv.LINE_8, True)

# display image
cv.imshow("", binary_image)
cv.waitKey()
```