# Python OpenCV added text not good quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am adding text in OpenCV like this...

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

cv2.putText(img,'Hack Projects',(10,500), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This works, but the text is not very good quality. Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it is natural - text is always so ugly.

Comment: you can put image with text or use `pillow` to put text - [Load TrueType Font to OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv)

Answer (score 25):

As noted in the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html), text in OpenCV looks better if you add `lineType = cv2.LINE_AA` to give you anti-aliased lines instead of the default `cv.LINE_8`.

Changing your code to:

```
cv2.putText(img,'Hack Projects',(10,500), font, 1,(255,255,255),2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

changes the image from this:

[image: text with no anti-aliasing]

to this:

[image: text with anti-aliasing]