# Writing an emoji on an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, opencv3.0, emoji

I would like to know if it is possible to write an emoji on an image with OpenCV.

This is what I have so far.

```
import cv2
import emoji

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
tick=str(emoji.emojize(':heavy_check_mark:'))
cv2.putText(img, tick,(5,5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX , 1, (255, 255, 255),3)
cv2.imshow('result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code does not work and I don't know why. Is it possible to load the tick emoji as an image (say img2) and then 'paste' it on some coordinate?

I am using python 3.7.6 on a windows.

Comment: you have to use the font that contains emoji characters, not only ASCII

Comment: @lenik I think there are only a handful of fonts with opencv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIL/Pillow and a suitable font like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import cv2
import emoji

# Open image with OpenCV
im_o = cv2.imread('start.png')

# Make into PIL Image
im_p = Image.fromarray(im_o)

# Get a drawing context
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_p)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial Unicode.ttf",32)
tick=str(emoji.emojize(':heavy_check_mark:'))
draw.text((40, 80),tick,(255,255,255),font=font)

# Convert back to OpenCV image and save
result_o = np.array(im_p)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result_o)
```

[image]

Note that Red and Blue channels are interchanged in OpenCV, so either reverse the channel ordering or use blacks, whites and greens. Reverse channel like this:

```
BGRimage = RGBimage[...,::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell, where did you find this ImageFont.truetype("Arial Unicode.ttf",32)

Comment: The "Arial Unicode" font? It's installed on all Macs by default. Else you can download it from the Net.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was really helpful. Stay safe  :)

Comment: Likewise. Good luck with your project and remember, questions (and answers) are free on StackOverflow, so come back and ask another if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this answer [Load TrueType Font to OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv) about loading TTF fonts in OpenCV:

[image]