# Overlaying on english text (chinese / Japanese) on Image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, multilingual

Opencv `cv::putText` doesn't seem to support the chinese or japanese text (unicode string) to be overlayed on the image.

Is any workaround available?

```
cv::putText(img, //target image
            "你好世界", //text
            cv::Point(10, img.rows / 2), //top-left position
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,
            1.0,
            CV_RGB(118, 185, 0), //font color
            2);
```

However, the text written on the image is: "??????"

Comment: The Hershey font has a very small number of glyphs.  You can install your own font.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv

Answer (score -1):

Non-English text overlaying using opencv C++ `cv::putText` Android native

Workaround:

1. https://github.com/castle-engine/android-freetype : Download and build freetype library for Android.
2. Build https://github.com/sibojia/cv-uni-text with freetype for Android.
3. For overlaying text on image, Use `uniText.PutText(img, "你好世界", p, color, false);` (instead of `cv::putTest`)